# extract details from from string

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a string in my database along with type `varchar`

```
{"available":"","bind":"0","hours":{"00:00":{"available":"","bind":"0","info":"","notes":"","price":"","promo":"","status":"none"}},"hours_definitions":[{"value":"00:00"}],"info":"","notes":"","price":"100","promo":"","status":"available"}
```

How do I extract the price from this?

Comment: I'm wondering how you got the data *into* the DB without knowing that this is JSON.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That string is valid JSON data, so you all you need to do is decode to an array for PHP to read. Like so:

```
$data = json_decode($string);
$price = $data->price;
```

To force it to be an array instead of an object, pass `true` to the second argument of `json_decode`, like so:

```
$data = json_decode($string, true);
$price = $data['price'];
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like JSON to me, so the steps are really simple:
1. Use `json_decode($response, true)` to convert from JSON to an array.
2. Treat as a normal array.

As such, the following code should work fine for you

```
$info = json_decode($jsonCode, true);
$price = $info['price'];
```

And the price will be stored in `$price`, or just `$info['price']` if you don't need another variable for it.

`json_decode()`'s second argument means that it will return associative arrays (like the one you have here) as an array, rather than an object. It's usually more useful that way, however you could always set it to false (or just leave it out, as false is the default).

See [json_decode's PHP documentation page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) for more info on its arguments.

Comment: I was midway through writing this when the other one was submitted, didn't notice a new one until I'd submitted mine. Besides, mine has a link to the documentation page, the other one doesn't. Therefore, not the same.